# How do I include the word "Table" in the LoT for longtables?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, longtable

I'm working on my thesis using a package provided by the University. When I compile my document, the LoT is displayed as follows:
[image: LOT]
Do you know how can I include the word "Table" for the appendix C tables (C.1, C.2, C3)? Those tables are long tables.
I have seen the aux file of the appendix where I have those long tables that is compiled as follows:

```
\@writefile{lot}{\contentsline {table}{\numberline {C.1}{IEEE 118-bus test system - Bus data}}{64}{table.208}}
```

but I know that I need the same line as follows (instead of {C.1} I need {Table\nobreakspace C.1}):

```
\@writefile{lot}{\contentsline {table}{\numberline {Table\nobreakspace C.1}{IEEE 118-bus test system - Bus data}}{64}{table.208}}
```

Do you have ideas for correct this?

Comment: Whatever the solution ends up being, the university should apply the fix to their provided template.

Comment: Any news on this? A compilable example together with a link where this 'strange' template can be found would be very nice!!

Comment: Mike: You are right, but the solution that the University has is: cut manually the table into various tables and use a type of caption that doesn't increase the table counter.

Comment: @CatalinaGil: Who gave you this advice? :D

Comment: This is the site where I consult: http://www.itlearningpods.com/Latex/faq.html. There are FAQ about the package that I'm using (How can I put in a table that's longer than one page?)

Comment: I would like to send them other solution as the longtable, but then I have the problem with the LoT.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no setup or clue which class is uses, I provide a generic solution with `tocloft` and the `\cfttabpresnum` command (which uses the space before the table number is typeset in the `LoT`) as well as increasing the number width by adding some value to `\cfttabpresnumwidth`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{\tablename\ }
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{30pt}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables


\appendix
\chapter{Foo}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
foo & foo \\
\caption{This is my table}
\endfirsthead
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried with your solution but it returns text overlay for the other tables (It looks like include the word "Table" for tables and longtables, so the first tables have the word table + table + #+ caption)

Comment: Move the `\renewcommand` etc. to the appendix then